# Can't display content in the middle of an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have an HTML page created with HTML, Javascript and CSS. There is a left vertical nav-bar on the page but I can't display content (text) in the center of the page (see screenshot - can't get text to be displayed where the red oval is). [image: screenshot]

I've tried writing in between every single `<div>` tag on the page and at the beginning and end of the `<body>` section but to no avail, the content will not go there.

```css
/* Custom styles */

.navbar {
  height: 100vh;
  /* Make navbar take full height of the viewport */
  width: 250px;
  /* Set a fixed width for the navbar */
}

.navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Stack items vertically */
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
  /* Make nav items take full width of the navbar */
}

.nav-link {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Add border to the nav items */
  background-color: white;
  /* Set background color for the nav items */
  color: black;
  /* Set text color for the nav items */
  padding: 10px;
  /* Add padding inside the nav items */
  margin: 5px 0;
  /* Add some space between the nav items */
  border-radius: 0;
  /* Remove border radius to match the screenshot */
}


/* Adjust the active link style */

.nav-link.active,
.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  /* Change background color for active/hover/focus */
  color: black;
  /* Text color for active/hover/focus */
}


/* Remove default Bootstrap styles for active nav-link */

.nav-link.active {
  border-color: #e9ecef;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light" style="width: 280px;">

  <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-dark text-decoration-none">
    <span class="fs-4">Peeps</span>
  </a>
  <hr>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
              Home
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Org Chart
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              OKRs
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Performance
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Onboarding
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Learning & Development
            </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <div class="dropdown">

    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <strong>More</strong>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li>
        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container mt-3">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12 mb-3">

      <div class="p-3 box">

        <h2>Welcome to Peeps!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="p-3 box">
        <p>Recommendations on how to get started go here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div class="p-3 box">
        <p>Some relevant graphs will go here. This will likely be around employee data, and would be customizable. --></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Include Bootstrap JS and its dependencies -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your version of Bootstrap. That's critical information here. FYI, you're writing way too much CSS. Bootstrap does almost all of that for you. I suggest that you get to know your library a bit better.

Comment: You also should not be using a very old (alpha!) version of Bootstrap. Update to at least a stable 5.0, or ideally the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want to put where but to make the container content go to where your oval is just add to the body a flex and it should be good

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    /* Custom styles */
    
    .navbar {
      height: 100vh;
      /* Make navbar take full height of the viewport */
      width: 250px;
      /* Set a fixed width for the navbar */
    }
    
    .navbar-nav {
      flex-direction: column;
      /* Stack items vertically */
    }
    
    .nav-item {
      width: 100%;
      /* Make nav items take full width of the navbar */
    }
    
    .nav-link {
      border: 1px solid black;
      /* Add border to the nav items */
      background-color: white;
      /* Set background color for the nav items */
      color: black;
      /* Set text color for the nav items */
      padding: 10px;
      /* Add padding inside the nav items */
      margin: 5px 0;
      /* Add some space between the nav items */
      border-radius: 0;
      /* Remove border radius to match the screenshot */
    }
    /* Adjust the active link style */
    
    .nav-link.active,
    .nav-link:focus,
    .nav-link:hover {
      background-color: #e9ecef;
      /* Change background color for active/hover/focus */
      color: black;
      /* Text color for active/hover/focus */
    }
    /* Remove default Bootstrap styles for active nav-link */
    
    .nav-link.active {
      border-color: #e9ecef;
      background-color: #e9ecef;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="d-flex">

  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light" style="width: 280px;">

    <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-dark text-decoration-none">
      <span class="fs-4">Peeps</span>
    </a>
    <hr>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
              Home
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Org Chart
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              OKRs
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Performance
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Onboarding
            </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link link-dark">
              Learning & Development
            </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div class="dropdown">

      <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <strong>More</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="container mt-3">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 mb-3">

        <div class="p-3 box">

          <h2>Welcome to Peeps!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="p-3 box">
          <p>Recommendations on how to get started go here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="p-3 box">
          <p>Some relevant graphs will go here. This will likely be around employee data, and would be customizable. --></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Include Bootstrap JS and its dependencies -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```